# Django project not displaying some components

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

so I am building a Django web application, and it has a preview section and this preview section is supposed to display a main-experience and additional-experience however when the form is filled, the main-experience is not being displayed, only the additional-experience displays, its as if the main-experience is being filtered out when the additional-experience is being displayed. What should I change in the code, such that both main and additional experiences are displayed in the preview? The associated codes are below.

```
this is the code i have. both the views and the associated html:
 
views.py:

@login_required
def experience_v(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExperienceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            main_experience = form.save(commit=False)
            main_experience.user = request.user
            main_experience.is_main_experience = True
            main_experience.save()

            additional_experiences = experience.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(pk=main_experience.pk)

            for entry in additional_experiences:
                exp = experience.objects.create(
                    user=request.user,
                    position=entry.position,
                    company=entry.company,
                    startdate=entry.startdate,
                    enddate=entry.enddate,
                    roles=entry.roles
                )

            return redirect('education')
    else:
        form = ExperienceForm()

    return render(request, 'experience.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def preview(request):
    personal_info = personalinfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).last()
    main_experience = experience.objects.filter(user=request.user, is_main_experience=True).first()
    additional_experiences = experience.objects.filter(user=request.user).exclude(pk=main_experience.pk) if main_experience else []
    educations = education.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    certs = certificates.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'preview.html', {
        'personal_info': personal_info,
        'main_experience': main_experience,
        'additional_experiences': additional_experiences,
        'educations': educations,
        'certs': certs
    })
```

---

```
html:

<div class="preview-data">
  <h2>Experience</h2>
  <div class="experience-item">
    <p><span class="bred">Position</span>: {{ main_experience.position }}</p>
    <p><span class="bred">Company</span>: {{ main_experience.company }}</p>
    <p><span class="bred">Start Date</span>: {{ main_experience.startdate }}</p>
    <p><span class="bred">End Date</span>: {{ main_experience.enddate }}</p>
    <br>
    <p><span class="brendon">Roles</span>: {{ main_experience.roles }}</p>
  </div>

  {% for additional_experience in additional_experiences %}
    <div class="experience-item">
      <p><span class="bred">Position</span>: {{ additional_experience.position }}</p>
      <p><span class="bred">Company</span>: {{ additional_experience.company }}</p>
      <p><span class="bred">Start Date</span>: {{ additional_experience.startdate }}</p>
      <p><span class="bred">End Date</span>: {{ additional_experience.enddate }}</p>
      <br>
      <p><span class="bred">Roles</span>: {{ additional_experience.roles }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is that the length of the array your are iterating with is zero. To check the values of your var use [debug template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug):

Markup:

```
{% debug %}
```

Just be sure that the [DEBUG](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std-setting-DEBUG) setting is set to True